# How to get location

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I get my current location using WiFi programatically? I am inside a room with my WiFi machine.

I have two machines which have Wifi and I want to locate my current location on my Iphone.

So how can I get my current location using two machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to register your wifi routers at Skyhook for the wifi locating service to work

[LINK](http://skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/submit_ap.php)

Comment: Neat! Now, my iPhone will be able to tell whether I'm in my backyard or side yard...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check here http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/tutorial-requests/2343-tutorial-request-core-location.html